# recv() functions flag for taking the while buffer in one string [windows C]

Tags: c, windows, function, flags, recv

This code sends and recv s txt file perfectly but cannot do it to otehr formats like .exe or .img. Please help me with these as I need to use htonl or htons??
Take a look!!

Here is the server side recv function ::

```
 if (socket_type != SOCK_DGRAM)
        {

                fi = fopen (final,"wb");
                retval = recv(msgsock, recv_buf, strlen(recv_buf), 0);
                /*recv_buf[retval] = '\0';
                fprintf (fi,"%s",recv_buf);*/

                int i;
                i=atoi(recv_buf);
                char *q;
                q=(char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
                retval = recv(msgsock, q, strlen(q), 0);
                //printf ("%s",q);
                fwrite(q,i,1,fi);
                fclose(fi);

        }
        else
        {
            retval = recvfrom(msgsock,recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);
            printf("Server: Received datagram from %s\n", inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr));
            printf ("SOCK_DGRAM");
        }

        if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Server: recv() failed: error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(msgsock);
            //continue;
        }
        else
            printf("Server: recv() is OK.\n");

        if (retval == 0)
        {
            printf("Server: Client closed connection.\n");
            closesocket(msgsock);
                //continue;
        }
        printf("Server: Received %d bytes, data from client\n", retval);

The client side sending function :::

void send_command()
{
    int bytesent;
    FILE *file_out;
    //file_out = fopen(file_path,"rb");
    char str_all[100000];//flag [30]="end";

    ///////////////////////getsize//////////////
    char fsize[5];
    int filesize;
    file_out = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    fseek(file_out, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file_out);
    rewind (file_out);
    itoa (filesize,fsize,10);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    send (ConnectSocket, fsize, strlen (fsize), 0);

    char *r = (char *)malloc (filesize * sizeof(char));

    fread(r,filesize,1,file_out);
    bytesent = send( ConnectSocket, r, strlen(r), 0 );
    printf("\nClient: Bytes sent: %ld\n", bytesent);
    fclose (file_out);

    /*while (fscanf(file_out,"%s",&str_all) != EOF)
    {
        bytesent = send( ConnectSocket, str_all, strlen(str_all), 0 );
        printf("\nClient: Bytes sent: %ld\n", bytesent);
        //Sleep(500);
    }*/

    /*printf("%s",flag);
    send( ConnectSocket, flag, strlen(flag), 0 );*/
    WSACleanup();
    //return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there are multiple issues with your program.

- You are transferring binary data.  The receiver is only going to see a sequence of bytes.  There is no way for the receiver to know the end of the data, since all possible values of `char` are legal data values.  If you were sending text data, you could say that a `0` signifies the end of the data, but now you can't.  So, you have to decide on a "protocol" between the server and the client—the simplest is that the server sends the length of the data in the first 4 bytes (read up on `ntonl()` and `ntohl()` for how to do this portably).  Then, the receiver will know exactly how many bytes to read.
- You declare the receiver buffer as `char *recv_buf`, and similarly for `recv_buf1`.  You don't allocate any storage for any of the two pointers, so they aren't pointing to anywhere useful.  Then, your `recv` call is: `recv(msgsock, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0);`  This also has problems.  The first is the one mentioned above: you don't have storage for `recv_buf`.  The second is that after you *do* allocate storage for `recv_buf`, you are taking the size of a char pointer instead of the length of the buffer `recv` points to.  One easy way to solve both the issues would be to declare `recv_buf` as: `char recv_buf[SIZE];` and then use `sizeof recv_buf` in the `recv()` call.

I haven't looked at the rest of your code.  You probably need a good C and network programming introduction.

Comment: Allocating is a problem I found but I am really noob at this and learning it like 2 weeks now. htons is a solution I was thinking but cannot implement. Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: If allocating is a problem, you can use an array as I said, but in the long run, you should learn pointers and malloc and friends in C.  For networking, there are many good tutorials online, or you can read Stevens' books.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the null-termination of a C string with the end of a packet sent on a socket.  There is no "termination" of a packet, it's just a string of bytes.  Zeros are completely legal, and you pass (and receive) the length explicitly.  You certainly don't need to use the out-of-band facilities to receive multiple packets. Can you be more specific about what you're asking?

Comment: I want to send a file like .mp3 or any format and recive it and save it like .mp3. So the both sides have to send and recv simultaneously!! When I send a text file the server side recieves only the length before SPACE or ENTER(/n). So I need to send a file as it is. The problem is in the server side as it cannot recieve simultaneously.

Comment: I'm not following.  I think you need to back out and read a few tutorials on socket programming.  Stevens' Unix Network Programming is the classic book, but there's lots of web content available.